# How to post one of four text boxes value to controller from view using FormMethod.Post instead from query string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a search page with four text boxes (ID, batchID, EmployeeNumber, RefNumber)all are numbers. I don't want to use query string to send any of these values to controller. So I am using Form.Post method like below:

@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = Model.id }))

But I want to make it global, so that based on which text box user uses to search, that value should be send to the controller and it's type also if possible(Like they entered ID or batchID or....) so that it will be easy for me to search the database accordingly. Please somebody help.

FYI: my route looks like this in global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I am actually thinking to send value from a javascript method where i do all the conditions check.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a view model:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? BatchID { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public int? RefNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and then have the controller action you are posting to take this view model as parameter and you will be able to retrieve which values did the user entered in the textboxes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(SearchViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    if (model.Id != null)
    {
        // the user entered something into the textbox containing the id
    }

    if (model.BatchId != null)
    {
        // the user entered something into the textbox containing the batch id
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: The HTTP verb doesn't really matter. This will work with GET and POST.